# Pentaho report designer 8.3: crosstab report in Report header

Tags: pentaho, crosstab, pentaho-report-designer

1. I'm add a test query in dataset

```
select title as attr_value,
       to_char(s,'YYYY') AS dt_year,
       to_char(s,'mm') as dt_month,
       1 as data

from my_test_table, GENERATE_SERIES('2018-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp, '2018-05-01T00:00:00', '1 month' ) AS s

order by attr_value, dt_year, dt_month;
```

2. Add crosstab report element to Report Header section as inline
3. Add att_value to Row axis, dt_year and dt_month to Column Axis, data to Data Cell in Edit Crosstab window.

When i run a report, i get error

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportProcessingException: Failed to process the report
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processReport(AbstractReportProcessor.java:1479)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.preview.PreviewExcelAction$ExportTask.run(PreviewExcelAction.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.PaddingController.activate(PaddingController.java:159)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DataProcessor.advance(DataProcessor.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.GlobalMasterRow.advanceRecursively(GlobalMasterRow.java:302)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.GlobalMasterRow.advance(GlobalMasterRow.java:265)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performCommit(DefaultFlowController.java:142)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.JoinCrosstabFactHandler.commit(JoinCrosstabFactHandler.java:38)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.commit(ProcessState.java:952)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessCrosstabFactHandler.commit(ProcessCrosstabFactHandler.java:37)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.commit(ProcessState.java:952)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processPrepareLevels(AbstractReportProcessor.java:407)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:505)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processReport(AbstractReportProcessor.java:1433)
    ... 2 more
```

When i add crosstab over "Master report" -> "Add crosstab", the report successfully build. 
Why i cant build crosstab report added to the Report header? Eventually, i want to add 2 different crosstab tables in 2 excel sheets. One table on the first sheet, second table on the second sheet.